# Tableau keeps rounding decimals to integer in text table

Tags: integer, dataset, decimal, tableau-api, datasource

I'm trying to put some data in a text table on Tableau Public and have a column of decimals rounded to two places. However, Tableau keeps rounding them to the nearest integer. This happens regardless of calculation (i.e., sum, median, etc.).

The problem seems to vanish when I'm charting data outside of the text table. In bar plots, scatterplots, and so on, it maps the values to two decimal places. How can I get the text table to show the float value?

Comment: Can you share a copy of your workbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Tableau had the number format set to "Automatic", which rounds to an integer in text tables instead of showing float values. The problem can be fixed by clicking on the value under Measure Values, clicking Format, going to Pane, and changing to Number (Custom) or Number (Standard).

Answer (score 1):

1. Access your Data Source tab.

[image: Tableau - Access Data Source Menu]

2. Press the icon that appears in the top right corner in the column name. A menu like this will appear

[image: Tableau - Change the column data type]

3. Then, select `Number (decimal)` and it is done.

[image: Tableau - Numbers converted to decimal]

Comment: If you do this and are using an extract you may need to re-extract or reload your data for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your data. However, you could right click on the tick marks and click edit axis and then click tick marks. From there you can edit the major and minor tick marks to suite your needs. Also make sure that in the data portion of Tableau that your data is set to the decimal format.